# Calculus Second Derivative with Inflection Point and Tangent Slope

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question: a function of the form $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx$ has an inflection point at $ A (1,5)$. If the slope of the tangent at $A$ is $4$, find the values of $a$,$b$, and $c$

Hi I don't quite get this question. Can someone please help? At most I have gotten done is $y''=6ax+2b$, and by plugging in the inflection point $(1,5)$ into that gives me $b=-3a$, but I think this might be wrong? Can someone help?

Comment: Yes so far it is correct. Now find the slope using the first derivative and equate that to $4$.

Comment: What you have done so far is correct. Sub x = 1 and y’ = 4 into y’ = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c. Sub x =1 and y= 5 into the first equation. You now have 3 equations with 3 unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done so far is fine

Hint: At $A$, $y' = 4$

$$\implies 3a + 2b + c = 4$$

Now also, the point $(1,5)$ lies on the curve, so it must satisfy it's equation

$$5 = a + b + c$$

Along with the relation you already have, this makes 3 equations in 3 variables